# How to cache data asp.net mvc using Cache obect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am using data caching in my asp.net application. 
This is my interface for the ICacheProvider.cs

```
public interface ICacheProvider
{
    object Get(string key);
    void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime);
    bool IsSet(string key);
    void Invalidate(string key);
}
```

This the way I'm using caching in the services.

```
public List<EmployeeLookUp> GetEmployeeLookUp(RecordStatusEnum recordStatusEnum, int locatioId)
    {
        var status = (int)recordStatusEnum;

        var employeeData = Cache.Get("EmployeeLookUp") as IEnumerable;

        if (employeeData == null)
        {
            var result = MyDb.Employee.Where(w => w.Status == status && w.LocationId == locatioId).ToList().Select(s => new EmployeeLookUp()
            {
                EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId,
                DepartmentId = s.DepartmentId,
                EmployeeValue = string.Format("{0}{1}{2} {3} {4}", "[", s.CustomEmployeeId, "]", s.FirstName, s.LastName)
            }).ToList();

            if (result.Any())
                Cache.Set("EmployeeLookUp", result, 30);

            return result;
        }

        return (List<EmployeeLookUp>) employeeData;
    }
```

In the controller I'm using the returned of employees like this.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = _employeeServices.GetEmployeeLookUp(RecordStatusEnum.Active, User.GetCemexUser().LocationId);
        employees.Insert(0, new EmployeeLookUp() { EmployeeId = -1, EmployeeValue = "All" });

        var complexRosterViewModel = new ComplexRosterViewModel
        {
            EmployeeList = new SelectList(employees, "EmployeeId", "EmployeeValue"),
            ListEmployeeGroups = new SelectList(_employeeGroupServices.GetEmployeeGroup(RecordStatusEnum.Active, User.GetCemexUser().LocationId), "EmployeeGroupId", "Value"),
            ListDepartments = new SelectList(_departmentService.GetDepartments(RecordStatusEnum.Active,User.GetCemexUser().LocationId),"DepartmentId","Value")
        };

        return View(complexRosterViewModel);
    }
```

Now my problem is, when i'm reloading the page several times, the additional "All" option that I added additionally to the employee select list, has been added to cached object("EmployeeLookUp") several times. How this can be possible? I do not want the "All" option to be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you're using a reference to cached object.
If you change the object, it will reflect the changes in cached data.

[Asp.Net Cache, modify an object from cache and it changes the cached value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793084/asp-net-cache-modify-an-object-from-cache-and-it-changes-the-cached-value)

You must clone the object or create a new and copy the properties values (you can use AutoMapper to do it for you)

Hope it helps.